# Any ideas why Cisco 3560G switch isn't passing broadcasted Ethernet packets?

Tags: cisco, ethernet, multicast

I have a 24 port Cisco 3560G switch that I'm using to try and pass broadcasted Ethernet packets. I have a computer plugged into one port, and a IEC-61850 GOOSE publisher plugged into another port. Both devices have an IP address assigned, and I can ping each from the other. However, when I run tcpdump on the computer I'm not seeing the broadcasted GOOSE messages from the publisher device.

If I directly connect the two machines, I can see the GOOSE messages with tcpdump. I can also replace the Cisco switch with a simple NetGear 4-port switch and still see the GOOSE packets.

I need to use the Cisco switch such that I can leverage VLANs to eventually get the GOOSE packets to machines connected to other switches, but first I need to get this simple test case working.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's worth noting that GOOSE is a Layer 2 protocol, which is why my question focuses on broadcasting Ethernet packets.

Comment: What's the tcpdump syntax you're using to capture the frames?

Comment: Did you run span on the Cisco device to see if the data is transiting the switch properly?  While tcpdump is a great tool, it has it's limitations.  Configurations of the switchports, log entries from the swtich, and examples from the working capture may be helpful as well.

Comment: I'm simply running `sudo tcpdump -i eth0`. This shows the GOOSE messages when I'm directly connected to the GOOSE publisher. However, it doesn't show any GOOSE messages when going through the Cisco switch.

Comment: The switch does not have storm control or other security features configured?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to use `span` to see if data is transitioning the switch properly? As for switchport configurations, the two ports I'm using are configured as simple, plane-jane switchports (no access mode, no VLAN configured, etc).

Comment: It does not have storm control configured that I know of... I can post the running config if you like.

Comment: What happens when you add the `-e` flag to tell tcpdump to capture the ethernet header?

Comment: @Bryan, how to use span would really be another question, but for quick reference, see [here](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps708/products_tech_note09186a008015c612.shtml).

Comment: Ah yes, _that_ span command. My apologies... I've used it before but spaced when you mentioned it. I'll have to do some setup and capture, which might take me a while. I'll post back once I've had a chance to do that.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 7):

> GOOSE uses VLAN and priority tagging as per IEEE 802.1Q to have separate virtual network within the same physical network and sets appropriate message priority level. -- [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOOSE#Generic_Object_Oriented_Substation_Events_.28GOOSE.29)

That would suggest this traffic is actually within a VLAN. So even if it is broadcast (or multicast), it's only going to go where that VLAN goes.

`tcpdump` has a rather annoying feature of not showing vlan tags unless you get rather verbose with it. Use wireshark (or `tshark`) and look at the complete contents (every. single. bit.) in each frame. Also note, many modern NICs process the vlan tag internally, so the OS doesn't normally see them -- the interface must be in promiscuous mode to turn that off. (and some drivers *continue* to eat them even then.)

Comment: So if GOOSE is 802.1q tagging packets, I would expect the switch to drop them as malformed because the switchport is only configured as an access port.  Look for drop counters on the ingress switchport?

Comment: If it were an old (very old) switch, then maybe. A 3560 knows what 802.1q is, and should simply ignore the tagged frames on access ports. (note: a 2924 will crash if sent a tagged packet on an access port. nice bug!)

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing Ricky - if the Switch ignores the tagged frames, then they aren't going to get to the other switchports, which means the application isn't going to work, and the remote side won't see them in a sniffer trace because they never get there

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer Ricky. So... my GOOSE device has both its VLAN and Priority Tagging set to 0. Might this be what's causing the issue? I could have sworn it'd worked in the past, but perhaps not. As I said in my OP, things worked fine when using a dinky little Netgear 4 port switch. As such, I figured it should work with the 3560 when the ports were in basic switchport mode. Perhaps this isn't the case since the 3560 is VLAN-capable?

Comment: hey @RickyBeam - i have a special request. Could you create the tag "iec61850" for us, since you have the required 300 reputation, this would be nice. There are quite some questions out there, but its hard to find them since there is no common tag for them.
thanks in advance!